# Is there any other way that we can take auto backup in oracle 11g apart from RMAN?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

I have tried with RMAN. But is there any other possible way that we can backup database and tables. backup using queries or stored procedures is possible?

Comment: Maybe you should ask this question better at this page: [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I want to take backup once in a week or a particular time period automatically. Is that possible using stored procedure?

Comment: Making a dump with Oracle Data Pump (`expdp`) could be a solution. However, you cannot trigger it by a stored procedure. Use `cron` or Windows `Task Scheduler` for this.

Comment: I think it is important to clarify; if you are just taking an export of your database you are only backing up the data inside of it and not the critical control file needed for a database restore. If you are just `expdp`'ing your database thinking you are backing it up you are creating a recipe for disappointment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes [there is a way](http://www.dba-oracle.com/p_dbms_backup_restore.htm) but in my opinion its a bad one.
Investigate the DBMS_BACKUP_RESTORE package:
Example control-file recovery:

```
DECLARE
devtype varchar2(256);
done boolean;
BEGIN
devtype := dbms_backup_restore.DeviceAllocate (type => '',ident => 'FUN');
dbms_backup_restore.RestoreSetDatafile;
dbms_backup_restore.RestoreDatafileTo(dfnumber => 1,toname => 'D:\ORACLE_BASE\datafiles\SYSTEM01.DBF');
dbms_backup_restore.RestoreDatafileTo(dfnumber => 2,toname => 'D:\ORACLE_BASE\datafiles\UNDOTBS.DBF');
--dbms_backup_restore.RestoreDatafileTo(dfnumber => 3,toname => 'D:\ORACLE_BASE\datafiles\MYSPACE.DBF');
dbms_backup_restore.RestoreBackupPiece(done => done,handle => 'D:\ORACLE_BASE\RMAN_BACKUP\MYDB_DF_BCK05H2LLQP_1_1', params => null);
dbms_backup_restore.DeviceDeallocate;
END;
/
```

RMAN is Oracle's recovery management tool and it should be used to take and validate your backups. If you are using a `expdp` method to backup your database you are simply taking a snapshot and [snapshots are not backups.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/documentation/rman-fra-snapshot-322251.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Oracle SQL Developer to do a database backup. Go to Tools ---> Database Export...

Comment: That's not a "backup" that's a "database dump" (aka "snapshot")

Answer (score 1):

You can take logical backup like export utility and latest one datapump. Using datapump if you want to take backup (query based) then you can use "expdp" utility as following....

expdp scott/password@tstdb schemas=SCOTT include=TABLE:"IN ('DEPT')" query=emp:"where deptno > 10" directory=TESTDP_DIR dumpfile=SCOTT-expdp.dmp logfile=SCOTT-expdp.log

After taking backup of DEPT table you can import in your database any time using utility of "impdp".